# Changing the "From" address when integrating SendMail with Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, sendmail

I recently installed SendMail on my system to use for sending email from a Rails3 project. The installation went fine and I was sending emails in no time. The only problem is, when a user receives an email, the "From" address has a hostname of `echo4.bluehornet.com`

I followed a tip [here](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/sendmail-masquerading-configuration-howto.html) and everything ran with no errors, but it did not change the results.

My guess is that my emails are being proxied through whatever SMTP server SendMail is configured to use. Is there any way around this? Can I configure things so that the "From" address shows up with the domain I want?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to configure sendmail to "masquerade" as a different host.  It was the numerous times when I delved into the `sendmail.cf` (or sendmail.mc which you can compile to sendmail.cf) that I sought an alternative.

I decided for my purposes (typically acting as a relay server from an application to my main SMTP service), postfix is significantly easier to configure, and easier still is exim.  Actually, I don't mean to throw anything except sendmail under the bus -- postfix is a full-featured email server, just about 50x easier to set up, especially for this kind of thing.

My best advice is to use Exim (or postfix, if it's installed already) to relay to a mail-sending service like SendGrid, which makes all of the headaches of mail sending go bye-bye.  If you're using Amazon AWS, they have a new mail sending service as well.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I actually already tried the masquerading (see the link in my question) and that did nothing for me. I will take a look at exim and postfix but I would still like to know how I can solve my problem in SendMail.

Comment: :-) The reason I switched to more modern mailers is that when I tried sendmail configuration it never seemed to work for me, either!

Comment: Actually I just realized that I made one mistake when I tried changing the configuration. I made the change and now it works. Thanks!

Comment: That's no excuse for not changing to Postfix :-)  (Can you tell, I have had many dark evenings doing battle with sendmail!)